# How would I start becoming knowledgable about hacking and able to do it?

Tags: web-browser

Is there a site I can start reading tutorials to simpler stuff to build up my skills??? Or is someone willing to give me a task (easy one) to do?

Comment: This question is likely to be closed, due to the fact that it encourages subjective answers.

Comment: Not very specific. In all honesty, if you have to even ask a question like this your future as a hacker will probably be extremely limited.

Comment: have you even looked? There are many high-quality sites.

Comment: You really should start using Google, simply searching up items about "beginning hacking" can give you stuff to start on... But here are some starter websites you can try, each level on these sites gives you links to how to learn to get past it. [www.hackthissite.org](https://www.hackthissite.org/) https://www.hackthis.co.uk/

Answer (score 2):

I know it seems at first to be such an enormous field that's it's just too hard to know where to start, so please ignore the abruptness of some of the responses (but do consider the intended communication).

This, however is not the right forum for this particular question, as has been mentioned above. This is the place to come when you have a specific technical question.

Try searching "Hacker High School". That's a great place to start.

Another worthwhile detail is understanding what hacking actually is and where the word originates. There's some argument about it but it's likely to have grown out of the world of early hobby/interest electronics like model trains and radio. A hacker is a person who hacks away at a problem until they find a solution. In essence it only has anything to do with security when someone is trying to hack away at the problem of accessing stuff they are not supposed to. Hacking and Security are not conjoined twins.

This is why you copped the remarks above. Because hacking is a mentality, and hackers tend to be a very proud bunch. Forgive them. Their gains have been hard won and there is oft a sentiment that yours should be too.

Enjoy the adventure.

Comment: and my apologies for giving an answer filled with subjectivity. But being not to far out of OP's situation I feel the need to help.

Answer (score 2):

```
                            Hacking
                            /      \
                           /        \
                          /          \
                Script Kidde        Genius

         1>Staight away start      1>Start with basics and move up the ladder.
           with Tutorials.         2>Program ,program and program  in many languages.   
         2>Hacking forums.         3>Create your own tools.
         3>Use tools.              4>Reverse .
         4>Get caught.             5>Keep learning and share knowledge go conferences etc
                                   6>Learn internals of linux+ unix + Mac + Windows OS.
                                   7>Gain respect.
```

If you like pictorial representation visit :
https://twitter.com/IBMSecurity/status/561276505335296000

Comment: I feel like everything on the "genius" list is a convenient byproduct of looping through step 5 for a few years.